# Exception occured while fetching the records near "table": syntax error In Python

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, exception

```
Code:
import sqlite3



def create_connection(db_file):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect("vienkarsaDB.db3")
    except Exception as err:
        print("Exception occured while trying to make connection", err)
    else:
        try:
            cur=conn.cursor()
            query= """SELECT * Cilvēki"""
            cur.execute(query)
            row=cur.fetchall()
            print(row)
        except Exception as err:
            print("Exception occured while fetching the records", err)
        else:
            print("Completed")
        finally:
            cur.close()
    finally:
        conn.close()
    return conn
create_connection("vienkarsaDB.db3")
```

Outprint:

```
Exception occured while fetching the records near "Cilvēki": syntax error
```

I want to print my SQL table row, which I have imported, row name, table name, checked, both names entered correctly. Can anybody explain why it didn't print what I wanted? Thank you!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Does it support non-Ascii characters in table names?

Comment: @jarlh Im using RDBMS.

Comment: query= """SELECT * FROM Cilvēki"""

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of your query is not right. You need to use **from** before table name

Instead of

```
SELECT * Cilvēki
```

Please use

```
SELECT * from Cilvēki
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Reckless mistake I have made.

Comment: As long as we learn from our mistake those are priceless. Best wishes.